# CASE and CAST Teradata - Returns timestamp and date

Tags: sql, casting, case, teradata

I'm trying to cast to `TIMESTAMP` one column in a `CASE` statement, but it keeps returning a `date` instead of a `timestamp`.

```
CASE 
    WHEN C.col IS NOT NULL AND b.Col IS NULL
        THEN    col_date_1
    ELSE  CAST(col_date_2 AS TIMESTAMP)
    END 
    AS Col_Date_G
```

I know that it is possible to `CAST` the `CASE` statement but that solution does not work for me since I need `col_date_1` to be a `date` and not a `timestamp`. So I cannot apply the "standard" solution.

Someone knows any workaround?

Comment: Do you mean you sometimes want the case to return date, and sometimes timestamp? Can't be done.

Comment: @jarlh I want that when it selects col_date_1 it is a date and when it selects col_date_2 it's a timestamp. Can that be done?

Comment: No, it can't.  A case expression always returns the same data type.